# Backup pending for this resource

Tags: moodle

I have a site customized by moodle 3.9.2. Now, I want to delete a course but I can't. An announcement "Backup pending for this resource" appears when I delete it. Please help me.

Comment: Try running cron, it might be an automated backup that's not finished or stuck - from the moodle root directory `php admin/cli/cron.php`